# How to translate a form in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, translation, django-i18n

I want to translate a django form. How do I translate the labels of the fields?

I tried `field.label=ugettext_lazy(field.label)`, but the labels are not getting populated in django.po file

I may have gotten the concept of ugettext_lazy wrong, I think

In simple terms I want the field labels to be put into django.po file.

The other translations done using `ugettext` and `{% trans %}` tag are working well

I have been able to translate the fields based on a model by setting `verbose_name` but when I try that for a form field I get a `TypeError`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    f1 = forms.CharField(label= ugettext_lazy('field label'))
```

Answer (score 11):

I will precise that :

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
...
first_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'First name'))
```

It's likely to raise an error because forms cannot manage well a proxy object like
_(u'First name'), and the result in rendering is a void form.
I tested this on python2.x and django 1.3/1.4

The reason is due to the compiled .po messages initially created by different o.s. and libraries (it can depend by python,django,os. libraries  versions).
When you have this error you must re-create the localized messages.

Answer (score 8):

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
first_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'First name'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative way, you can add script to your template.html

```
<script>
        labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
        for (var j = 0; j < labels.length; j++) {   
             if (labels[j].textContent == "Username:") labels[j].textContent =    "Логін   ";
             if (labels[j].textContent == "First name:") labels[j].textContent =  "Ім'я    ";
             if (labels[j].textContent == "Last name:") labels[j].textContent =   "Прізвище";
             if (labels[j].textContent == "Email address:") labels[j].textContent =   "Email адреса ";
             if (labels[j].textContent == "Password:") labels[j].textContent =        "Пароль            ";
             if (labels[j].textContent == "Confirm password:") labels[j].textContent =        "Підтвердити пароль";
             };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [gettext_lazy()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy) and [label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/fields/#label) in [forms.CharField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/fields/#charfield) as shown below:

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

first_name = forms.CharField(label=_('First name'))
```